# StackOverflow error in Android

Tags: android, exception, view, stack-overflow

I am running my app in **Acer tablet**, app get **crash** every time, and app is perfectly run on  **Samsung** tablet.

```
02-13 09:48:05.400: D/OpenGLRenderer(7270): Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-13 09:48:07.700: D/dalvikvm(7270): GC_CONCURRENT freed 13419K, 65% free 7568K/21063K, paused 2ms+4ms
02-13 09:48:07.830: I/dalvikvm(7270): threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Landroid/widget/TextView;.onCreateDrawableState:LI
02-13 09:48:07.830: I/dalvikvm(7270):   method requires 36+20+20=76 bytes, fp is 0x4001732c (44 left)
02-13 09:48:07.830: I/dalvikvm(7270):   expanding stack end (0x40017300 to 0x40017000)
02-13 09:48:07.830: I/dalvikvm(7270): Shrank stack (to 0x40017300, curFrame is 0x40017500)
02-13 09:48:07.830: D/AndroidRuntime(7270): Shutting down VM
02-13 09:48:07.830: W/dalvikvm(7270): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a561f8)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270): java.lang.StackOverflowError
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.View.getDrawableState(View.java:11556)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4863)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10983)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10422)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10986)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10422)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10420)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10420)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10420)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10986)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1524)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10422)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10986)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
02-13 09:48:07.860: E/AndroidRuntime(7270):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10422)
```

Please help me how to solve this issue

Comment: @DigveshPatel, just i added fragment in java class. Thanks

Comment: please edit logcat to have all the stacktrace

Answer (score 7):

`StackOverflowError` Thrown when `the depth of the stack of the running program exceeds some platform or VM specific limit`. Typically, this will occur only when a program becomes infinitely recursive, but it can also occur in correctly written (but deeply recursive) programs.

Perhaps you have too many nested layouts.

Answer (score 4):

**StackOverflowError** occurs when you are having two may views inside views (i.e. nested views), like if you are 15 levels deep.

**How to solve it:**

It is not easy, you just have to remove nested views (layouts). So, try to use relative layout as much as possible.

**Reproducing StackOverflowError:**

The most annoying thing about `StackOverflowError` is that, I will not occur on all device. Old device (with less memory, cpu power) will have have this error but high end devics might not produce this error. So best way to produce/resolve this issue is to test it on different emulators.

Answer (score 3):

Generally `StackOverflowError` occurs whenever you have too many nested viewgroups which are one inside another. I think in your layout to have kept too many of views and called recursively which is calling eachother recursively and leading the heap memory of getting out of specific limit.

Just check out your layout using `HierarchyViewer` which will show you that how you have designed your layout.