# Stackoverflow Exception while seeting text in dynamic Edittext in Android

Tags: android, stack-overflow

I have multiple dynamic edittext. I want to change the value of the next edittext on changing the value of previous edittext. But my code is giving StackOverflow Exception. Please help.

code:

```
       edt_pay_option.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            sum = 0.0;
            last = allEds.get(allEds.size()-1);
            for (int j = 0; j < allSign.size(); j++) {
                sign[j] = allSign.get(j).getText().toString();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < allEds.size(); i++) {


                amount[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
                if (!allEds.get(i).getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    if (allEds.get(i).getText().toString().equals(".")) {
                        allEds.get(i).setText("0.");
                    }
                    if (sign[i] == "-") {
                        value = Double.parseDouble("-"
                                + allEds.get(i).getText().toString());
                    } else {
                        value = Double.parseDouble(""
                                + allEds.get(i).getText().toString());
                    }
                } else {
                    value = 0.0;
                }


                List<Double> value1 = new ArrayList<Double>();

                value1.add(value);
                for (int j = 0; j < value1.size(); j++) {
                    sum = sum + value1.get(j);
                }

                paidAmount = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("0.00")
                        .format(sum));
                outstandingAmount = totalAmount - paidAmount;

                try {
                    if(allEds.size()>1){


last.setText(Double.toString(outstandingAmount));
                    ;
                        }
                } catch (StackOverflowError e) {

                }



            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Remove the unwanted views and layout in the xml file

Comment: have a look to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749387/stackoverflow-erro-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change your `EditText` from `TextChangeListener`?
It is not possible because it would invoke itself.

Comment: yes I am. If I enter any value in 1 EditText it will perform calculation and the reult will automatically set in the next EditText.

Comment: Check out your imported libraries at gradle Android Studio and just make the same at Eclipse